# Difficulty parsing a double - String

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I have a `double` value (let's say 22.35). I need to parse it into a `String` and get 2235. The following code is not working properly.

```
double totalPrice = 22.35;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String[] temp = df.format(totalPrice).split(".");
String amount = temp[0] + temp[1];
```

I keep getting an exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`. What is another way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `int totalCents = (int)(22.35d*100);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Looks like an answer to me, with perhaps a sentence or two for explanation. +1

Comment: Why don't you just replace dot character by an empty one?

Comment: @jmort253  Great comment!  :)  Let's hope that it 'sounds better' (as in - does not get deleted) the way you said it.

Answer (score 4):

If your values don't exceed, after multiplication by 100, MAX_INT, multiply them:

```
double totalPrice = 22.35;
int iPrice = (int) (totalPrice * 100);
String sPrice = "" + iPrice;
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry, forgot to cast.

Comment: @userunknown - Congrats on the 10k!

Comment: @jmort253: Thanks. The last 2000 happen by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
double totalPrice = 22.35;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String price = df.format(totalPrice).replace(".", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this: just change the regex "." to " \."!

```
String[] temp = df.format(totalPrice).split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work no matter how high a number you try to apply it to:

```
double num = 22.35;
String concatenate = "" + num;
String parsedNum = concatenate.replace(".", "");
```

Hope this helps you.